# Username validation not working in CreateUserWizard

Tags: validation, umbraco, createuserwizard

I have a CreateUserWizard for users to register new account.

I have added my text fields and required field validators

However when I click register button with empty username I get error:

> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: The username of a Member must be different from an emptry string
>
> Parameter name: loginName

The username field has its requiredfieldvalidator so it should work. I have also added

> UserNameRequiredErrorMessage

property to the wizard but it didn't make a difference.

*loginName* mentioned in the above error message is a control for LoginView. I have this on the same page but it's not used during the registration for CreateUserWizard.

Why is this happening?

My code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlRegister" runat="server">

<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="cuwRegister" RequireEmail="false"
OnContinueButtonClick="cuwRegister_ContinueButtonClick" 
    OnCreatedUser="cuwRegister_CreatedUser"  
runat="server">
<WizardSteps>
    <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="uxValSummaryRegister" DisplayMode="BulletList" runat="server" ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard" ForeColor="#FF5555" />
<asp:Literal ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>

            <div class="row">
                <label>Email</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" />
      <asp:requiredfieldvalidator runat="server" 
                        controltovalidate="UserName" 
                        tooltip="Email is a required"
                        id="reqEmail" 
                        validationgroup="CreateUserWizard" 
                        errormessage="Email is a required" Display="Dynamic">
                        *
                      </asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revEmail" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="UserName" 
                    ErrorMessage="Enter correct email address" 
                    ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*">*
                </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label><umbraco:Macro Item="Confirm email" Alias="Dictionary-Item" runat="server" /></label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmEmail" runat="server" />
      <asp:requiredfieldvalidator runat="server" 
                        controltovalidate="ConfirmEmail" 
                        tooltip="Confirm Email address is a required"
                        id="reqConfirmEmail" 
                        validationgroup="CreateUserWizard" 
                        errormessage="Confirm Email address is a required">
                        *
                      </asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
                <asp:CompareValidator runat="server" 
                    id="cmpNumbers" 
                    controltovalidate="ConfirmEmail" 
                    controltocompare="UserName" 
                    operator="Equal"
                    type="String"
                    errormessage="Email and Confirm Email do not match" />
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label><umbraco:Macro Item="Password" Alias="Dictionary-Item" runat="server" /></label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
      <asp:requiredfieldvalidator runat="server" 
                        controltovalidate="Password" 
                        tooltip="Password is a required"
                        id="reqPassword" 
                        validationgroup="CreateUserWizard" 
                        errormessage="Password is a required">
                        *
                      </asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label><umbraco:Macro Item="Confirm password" Alias="Dictionary-Item" runat="server" /></label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
      <asp:requiredfieldvalidator runat="server" 
                        controltovalidate="ConfirmPassword" 
                        tooltip="Confirm Password is a required"
                        id="Requiredfieldvalidator1" 
                        validationgroup="CreateUserWizard" 
                        errormessage="Confirm Password is a required">
                        *
                      </asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
                <asp:CompareValidator runat="server" 
                    id="CompareValidator1" 
                    controltovalidate="ConfirmPassword" 
                    controltocompare="Password" 
                    operator="Equal"
                    type="String"
                    errormessage="Password and Confirm Password do not match" />
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <label><umbraco:Macro Item="First name" Alias="Dictionary-Item" runat="server" /></label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label><umbraco:Macro Item="Surname" Alias="Dictionary-Item" runat="server" /></label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSurname" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label><umbraco:Macro Item="Date of birth" Alias="Dictionary-Item" runat="server" /></label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="DOB" runat="server" />
      <asp:requiredfieldvalidator runat="server" 
                        controltovalidate="DOB" 
                        tooltip="Date of birth is a required"
                        id="Requiredfieldvalidator2" 
                        validationgroup="CreateUserWizard" 
                        errormessage="Date of birth is a required">
                        *
                      </asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
            </div>

            </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
    <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep1" runat="server"></asp:CompleteWizardStep>
</WizardSteps>
```

and in the code behind:

```
protected void cuwRegister_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string email = cuwRegister.UserName;
    string username = cuwRegister.UserName;
    string password = cuwRegister.Password;
    Page.Validate("CreateUserWizard");
    if(Page.IsValid)
        CreateUser(email, username, password);
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnRegister.Text = cuwRegister.CreateUserButtonText = umbraco.library.GetDictionaryItem("Register");
    cuwRegister.DuplicateUserNameErrorMessage = umbraco.library.GetDictionaryItem("Duplicated email");
    cuwRegister.DuplicateEmailErrorMessage = umbraco.library.GetDictionaryItem("Duplicated email");
    cuwRegister.InvalidEmailErrorMessage = umbraco.library.GetDictionaryItem("Email address incorrect");
    cuwRegister.InvalidPasswordErrorMessage = umbraco.library.GetDictionaryItem("Password incorrect");
    cuwRegister.EmailRequiredErrorMessage = umbraco.library.GetDictionaryItem("Email required");
    cuwRegister.PasswordRequiredErrorMessage = umbraco.library.GetDictionaryItem("Password required");
    cuwRegister.ConfirmPasswordCompareErrorMessage = umbraco.library.GetDictionaryItem("Password not matching");
    cuwRegister.UserNameRequiredErrorMessage = umbraco.library.GetDictionaryItem("Password not matching");


    Login lwPanelLogin = (Login)lwLogin.FindControl("lwLoginPanel");
    if (lwPanelLogin != null)
    {
        lwPanelLogin.TitleText = umbraco.library.GetDictionaryItem("Already registered? Log in here");
        lwPanelLogin.LoginButtonText = umbraco.library.GetDictionaryItem("Login");
        lwPanelLogin.RememberMeText = umbraco.library.GetDictionaryItem("Remember me next time");
        lwPanelLogin.PasswordLabelText = umbraco.library.GetDictionaryItem("Password");
        lwPanelLogin.UserNameLabelText = "Email";
    }
}

protected void CreateUser(string email, string username, string password)
{
    bool isLoggedIn = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    if (Membership.GetUserNameByEmail(email) == null)
    {
        MembershipUser member = Membership.CreateUser("aaa", password, email);
    }

    if(!isLoggedIn)
        if (System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser(username, password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);
        }
}
```

(Note that I use Username field to get email and then email is used to login)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setting your Username within the "OnCreatedUser" method. This is fired *after* the wizard has attempted to create that user. 
You will need to set your username within the "OnCreatingUser" method, which is fired beforehand.

As quick win, try using this:

```
... 
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="cuwRegister" RequireEmail="false" OnContinueButtonClick="cuwRegister_ContinueButtonClick" OnCreatingUser="cuwRegister_CreatedUser" runat="server">
   <WizardSteps>
...
```